# Найти в тексте слова, которые не обрамлены < >

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

**Пример текста:**

> Объект <Московский государственный **университет** имени М. В.
>   Ломоносова> — ведущий университет России. Этот университет был основан
>   в 1755 году...

Нужно такое регулярное выражение, которое будет искать в тексте все слова "университет", кроме тех, которые обрамлены символами < и > (выделил в примере жирным слово, которое искаться не должно).

**Для регулярок используется pcre (PHP).**

Уже час голову ломаю, ничего работающего придумать не удалось...

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = "Объект <Московский государственный университет имени М. В. Ломоносова> — ведущий университет России. Этот университет был основан в 1755 году..."

s.replace(/<[^>]*>|(университет)|./g, (m, u, i, s) => u && console.log(i))
```

Выводит 81 и 106.

Answer (score 2):

То же, что и в ответе @Qwertiy, но на PHP:

```
$replacer = function( $match ) {
    if ( @$match[1] ) {
        return "институт";
    } else {
        return $match[0];
    }
};

$text = "Объект <Московский государственный университет имени М. В. Ломоносова> — ведущий университет России. Этот университет был основан в 1755 году...";
$re = "/(университет)|<.*?>/ius";
echo preg_replace_callback( $re, $replacer, $text );
```

http://ideone.com/CZVo9e

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант поиска для последующей замены

```
preg_replace('/\G(?(?=<)(?>[^>]+)|[^<])+?\Kуниверситет/giu','институт',$str);
```

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/cU7rE8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно сначала убрать из строки содержимое <...>, а затем уже выполнять поиск по изменённой строке.

Пример на perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$\="\n";
my $line = 'Объект <Московский государственный университет '.
    'имени М. В. Ломоносова> — ведущий университет России. '.
    'Этот университет был основан в 1755 году...';

# Этап 1-й удалить лишнее: всё, что внутри <...>    
my $string = ($line =~ s/<.*>//rg);

# Этап 2-й затем обычный поиск по уже изменённой строке.
while ($string =~ /(университет)/g) {
    print $1;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, удалять что-либо из строки не вариант, все должно остаться.

Comment: Строка остаётся нетронутой (переменная $line), а её изменённый вариант в ($string) и используется для поиска.

Comment: Дело в том, что эти 2 найденный вхождения, которые не обрамлены < > мне потом нужно будет заменить.

Answer (score 0):

```
(университет)(?![^>]*>)
```

Пропускает слово, если далее присутствует закрывающая `>`, но не проверяет что была открывающая `<`. (К сожалению lookbehind assertion должно быть фиксированной длины.)

Comment: php же умеет предпросмотр назад, в отличие от js.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, но только когда заранее можно вычислить длину предшествующей строки.

Comment: Зачем длину? Предпросмотр же не входит в совпадение.

Comment: Я о том, что если я напишу `(?<!<[^<]*)университет` компилятор регулярных выражений выдаст ошибку "lookbehind assertion is not fixed length"